# MacOS - "aws: Command not found." although file showing in "/usr/local/bin/"

Tags: macos, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, sudo

For a current project, I am planning to install and configure the AWS Command Line Interface.

I have completed the installation both via `sudo` and via the `MacOS Installer` and the aws file is showing in `/usr/local/bin/` as intended.

When using the command `aws` in the `MacOS Terminal` to e.g. check the for the aws version (`aws --version`), I am hiwever receiving the message `aws: Command not found.`

What can be the reason for that, as the file is in the folder? I was thinking that I might have installed AWSCLI to a wrong folder but `/usr/local/bin/` is the location recommended in the installation guidelines. Does someone have a smart solution for the situation?

Comment: is /usr/local/bin in your PATH?

Comment: Good point - I did not add it to the PATH as the AWSCLI guide mentions this is not necessary. When adding it, the file is found by the terminal. Is there any way to avoid having to add the path each time without using cd ~/?

Comment: for bash,  add  ```export PATH=/usr/local/bin:${PATH}``` to your .bashrc  (or .bash_profile)..  can't remember for OSX.

Comment: That's great, many thanks.

Comment: On macOS, /usr/local/bin is normally in `PATH` by default. If it's not there, that suggests that something is removing it, which is not really a good idea. I would take a look at your shell startup files to see what might be removing it, rather than hiding the problem by re-adding it.